Unable to format YAML
I Have been facing trouble with YAML format
Code  successfully build, But facing issue when I am trying to run application.
Configuration is fine, because I have been picking response from YAML for an other API which is totally fine.
JSON (This is a SAMPLE JSON to whom I am converting into YAML)
{
    "businessTypes": [
        {
            "type": "SOLE_PROPRIETORSHIP",
            "accountTypes": [
                {
                    "type": "MY_NAME",
                    "products": [
                        "ISLAMIC_CURR",
                        "ISLAMIC_SAV",
                        "CONV_CURR",
                        "CONV_SAV"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "BUSINESS_NAME",
                    "products": [
                        "ISLAMIC_CURR",
                        "ISLAMIC_SAV",
                        "CONV_CURR",
                        "CONV_SAV"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "PARTNERSHIP",
            "accountTypes": [
                {
                    "type": "BUSINESS_NAME",
                    "products": [
                        "ISLAMIC_CURR",
                        "ISLAMIC_SAV",
                        "CONV_CURR",
                        "CONV_SAV"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

EXCEPTION message
The exception message provided by Spring Boot configuration.
    Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0]
            Value: "ISLAMIC_CURR"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 110:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1]
            Value: "ISLAMIC_SAV"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 111:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2]
            Value: "CONV_CURR"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 112:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3]
            Value: "CONV_SAV"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 113:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type
            Value: "MY_NAME"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 108:17
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0]
            Value: "ISLAMIC_CURR"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 116:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1]
            Value: "ISLAMIC_SAV"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 117:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2]
            Value: "CONV_CURR"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 118:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3]
            Value: "CONV_SAV"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 119:15
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
            Property: app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type
            Value: "BUSINESS_NAME"
            Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 114:17
            Reason: The elements [app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[0].type,app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[0],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[1],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[2],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].products[3],app.businesstypes[0].accounttypes[1].type] were left unbound.
        
    Action:

